# How to start a specific release version?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I am trying to run a specific OTP release version built at server, but I have no idea how to do so.

In the releases directory, I have those releases:

`releases/0.0.3
 releases/0.0.4
 releases/0.0.5`

I have ssh through the server, but I don't how to can I start a specific release to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give [kerl](https://github.com/kerl/kerl) a try. It's ideal for switching between different versions.